# How to fetch key value from a API response in RestAssured using java

Tags: rest, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath, automation-testing

I have a API response below. I want to fetch a value from the response which inside a JSON array.

```json
{
  "Code": [
    {
      "id": "string1",
      "istrue": false,
      Text": "hdjdjkdk123"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using JsonPath class to fetch

```java
String resp = response.asString();
JsonPath js = new JsonPath(resp);
js.get("ciext").toString();
```

Anyone please help me here how to get the value for "id" or "ciText" ???

Answer (score 0):

The correct path would be:

```java
js.get("cipherTexts[0].id")
//or
js.get("cipherTexts[0].cipherText")
```